# JQuery animate toggle on click for multiple elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

## Demo here

I'm building a display for information; when a user clicks on a thumbnail, a box opens up underneath it to display the info specific to that thumbnail (info is drawn from XHR, not working properly in jfiddle). The opening of the box isn't the problem - I'm trying to get the closing of the box right.

What I want to do is this:

```
if (box is closed) {
    open box;
}

if (box for this thumb is open) {
    close box;
}

if (box for another thumb is open) {
   close other box;
   on complete of close, open new box;
}
```

I also want to make a separate function for closing the box that I can attach to a close box icon.

How would I best go about this? I can't see how clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you answered your own question? [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: Toggle() would work if the item being clicked was the item being animated. In my case, the item being animated has not yet been added to the HTML - jquery does that as part of the on click event.

Answer (score 0):

One way I've done in the past is to add a marker css class to the open box.  You could easily do this if you're using jQuery animate by using the complete callback to add the class to the element you just opened.

Once you have that, your logic, in your click handler that triggers the animation, do the following: 
1) Check if the element that was clicked/is being open on has the opened class, and if so set some temporary flag to indicate this.

2)  Do a jQuery search for all elements that have the opened class, and animate their closing.

3) If your flag tells you the clicked element wasn't already open, animate it's opening, else do nothing.

Here's a simplified example where I have multiple divs which grow bigger and semi transparent when clicked on, but only one can be big at a time, and clicking on an already expanded div will shrink it back to normal.

```
$('div').on('click', pop);

function pop(event) {
    debugger;
    var alreadyPopped = false;
    if ($(event.target).hasClass('popped')) {
        alreadyPopped = true;
    }
    $('.popped').animate({
        height: 50, width: 50, opacity: 1
    }, 1000, "linear", function(e) {
      $('.popped').removeClass('popped');
    });

    if (!alreadyPopped) {
        $(event.target).animate({
        height: 200, width: 200, opacity: 0.5
    }, 1000, "linear", function(e) {
     $(event.target).addClass('popped');
    });
    }    
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ijoukov/zA87j/1/

Comment: Good suggestion, similar to what I already have. However, this assumes that the item being clicked is also the item being animated. In my case, it's not. See http://jsfiddle.net/KWBgS/ for my demo.

Comment: I'm not seeing why that makes a big difference.  The basic idea is still the same, make sure everything is closed, then open your desired div if needed.  As long as you can find the target item from the item clicked you're fine.  In this case you can do so because you always append the dropdown right after the click target.

Comment: Add this  quick and dirty code to the bottom of your if statement, and it should do what you want.  
                    `if(!$(this).next().hasClass('dropdown')) {
                    $(this).after('<div class="dropdown"></div>');
     $('.dropdown').animate({'height':'300px'}, 1000, function () {
                            ddopen = true;
                            $(this).load('http://www.simondoes.com.au/test2.html #content'+i, function() {$('#content'+i).fadeIn();});
                            $('#content'+i).fadeIn();  
                        });
                    }`

Answer (score 0):

After playing around for a while to rebuild the code, I found a solution. I think the key in this was using index() to identify the clicked button as a reference point for what needed to happen next.

Javascript:

```
//store for dropdown activity: false=inactive/true=active
var ddopen = false;
//store for last clicked button
var index;

//Create and animate/activate dropdown container
$.fn.ddExpand = function (btnNo) {
    // Identify parents of the button clicked, amd create the animating container
    var btn = $('#'+btnNo);
    btn.parent().after('<div class="box"></div>');

    //load content into container
    $('.box').load('test2.html #content'+btnNo);
    $('.box').show().animate({'height':'300px'}, 1000, function () {
        $('.content').fadeIn();     
    });
    //Declare dropdown as open/active
    ddopen = true;
    // Store button index for later reference
    index = btnNo;
}

//Deactivate/close and delete dropdown container
$.fn.ddCollapse = function (btnNo) {
    $('.content').fadeOut();
    $('.box').animate({'height':'0px'}, 500, function () {
        $(this).remove();

        //If function parameter IS a number, reactivate dropdown according to new button index / else / Declare dropdown as closed/deactivated
        (btnNo!=false) ? $(this).ddExpand(btnNo) : ddopen = false;
    });

}

$('.button').on('click', function () {
    //Capture index of button
    var btnNo = $('.button').index(this);
    //Silently add index of button as id attribute to button for later reference. This will also allow for extensibility should more buttons be added.
    $(this).attr('id', btnNo);

    //If dropdown is inactive
    if (ddopen == false) {
        //active dropdown according to button index
        $(this).ddExpand(btnNo);
    } else { //if dropdown is already active
        //if the button clicked now is different to last button clicked
        if (btnNo != index) {
            //pass new button index on to collapse current dropdown and reactive with new index
            $(this).ddCollapse(btnNo);
        } else { //if button clicked now is the SAME as last button clicked
        // close/deactivate existing dropdown and return to default state
        $(this).ddCollapse(false);
        }
    }
});

//process close button added to loaded content
$('body').on('click', '.close', function () {
    // close/deactivate existing dropdown and return to default state
    $(this).ddCollapse(false);
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="btnCase">
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
<div class="btnCase">
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
<div class="btnCase">
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
<div class="btnCase">
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
<div class="btnCase">
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```